# Cannot convert float float to float in initialization

Tags: c++

I hope you guys are doing well! I'm here looking for help regarding about an error I cannot quite figure out on C++. I am a beginner for C++ and overall new a coding in general. This assignment is due at 11:59pm, so answers would be greatly appreciated with an explanation. Thanks to all!

**Error:**

In function 'int main()':
28:7: warning: unused variable 'totalC' [-Wunused-variable]

In function 'float total_cost(int)':
66:13: error: cannot convert 'float (*)(float)' to 'float' in initialization

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath> 
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

//Prototypes:
//Gives user instructions 
void instructions(); 
//Asks user for number of books being bought and downloaded
int prompt();
//Calculation for Sub total without discount 
float calcSubTotal(float);
//Calculation for Discount 
float calcDiscount(int);
//Calculation for Total Cost
float total_cost(int);
//Outputs results for user 
void label(); 


        
int main()
{
instructions();
int nb = prompt(); //save value of prompt as pR
float subT = calcSubTotal(nb); //save value of calcSubTotal as subT
float Disc = calcDiscount(subT); //save value of calcDiscount as Disc
float totalC = total_cost(Disc); //save value of total_cost as totalc
label(); 
return 0;
}

//Instructions  Function 
void instructions(){
cout << "***************************************************************************" << endl; 
cout << " Hello and welcome to BandN Book Store!" << endl; 
cout << " Each eBook costs $8.99." << endl; 
cout << " Today, we are having a special where you can get 15% off your total order. " << endl;
cout << "***************************************************************************" << endl; 
}

//Number of books Function 
int prompt(){
    float books;
    cout << "How many ebooks do you wish to download?" << endl; 
    cin >> books;
return books; 
}

//calcSubTotal Function 
float calcSubTotal(float books){
    float Price_per_book = 8.99; 
    float subTotal = books * Price_per_book;    
return subTotal; 
}

//Discount Function 
float calcDiscount(int Price_Totaldisc){
    float subTotal = Price_Totaldisc;
    float disc = 0.15;  
    float discount = subTotal * disc; 
    float discount_value = subTotal - discount;
return discount_value; 
}

//Total Cost Fucntion
float total_cost(int dis_val){ 
float sub = calcSubTotal; //ERROR
float dis_value = dis_val; 
float totalcost = sub - dis_value; 

    return totalcost; 
}

//Prints Out results 
void label (int nb, float, float subT, float disc, float totalC){ 
    
cout << "***************************************" << endl; 
    cout << "The number of ebooks downloaded: " << nb << endl; 
    cout << setprecision(4); 
    cout << "Sub-total: " << "$" << subT << endl; 
    cout << setprecision(4); 
    cout << "Discount: " << "$" << disc << endl; 
    cout << setprecision(4);
    cout << "Total cost: " << '$' <<  totalC << endl; 
    cout << "***************************************" << endl; 
}
```

Comment: `calcSubTotal` is a function. Maybe you want to call it? `calcSubTotal(somevar)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, you're writing calcSubTotal like a variable when it is a function name. You need to say

```
float sub = calcSubTotal(books);
```

You need to call prompt() then calcSubTotal(books) then total_cost(dis_val)
I would define a float variables books and subtotal inside of total_cost()

```
float total_cost(int dis_val){ 
    float books = prompt();
    float subTotal = calcSubTotal(books);
    float sub = subTotal; //ERROR
    float dis_value = dis_val; 
    float totalcost = sub - dis_value; 

    return totalcost; 
}
```

Once this is fixed you need to fix the label() call inside of you main function. I'll let you do that, but if you need any help with it I will :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate the help Zac! I'll let you know about the label.

Comment: Yeah....I need help with the label! Haha. I apologize. Enlighten me with your code knowledge  about the label Zac!

Comment: @Jonathan Your label () function needs parameters to work. Make sure you give it all the inputs it needs.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing parameters in the `calcSubTotal` call. You need to write `float sub = calcSubTotal(inbooks)`.

Comment: There is no bugs if there is no specification. Maybe he really wants to assign that function so lines below should be fixed?

Comment: @MateuszDrost `float calcSubTotal(float);` is a specification.

Comment: @MateuszDrost From context, it seems highly unlikely that the OP meant to store the function pointer. The type specified is `float` and later on the code tries to subtract a value from it.